# Robot Framework: Timed out waiting for page load

Tags: robotframework

We have run our Robot Framework environment nearly one year without any problems, but now we get the error message:

```
TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page load.
Stacktrace:
    at Utils.initWebLoadingListener/< (file:///tmp/tmp77bOby/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9089)
    at WebLoadingListener/e (file:///tmp/tmp77bOby/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:5145)
    at WebLoadingListener/< (file:///tmp/tmp77bOby/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:5153)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///tmp/tmp77bOby/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)
```

What could be problem? I checked the disk space and there are disk space left.

Comment: When you watch the test, do you see that the page has finished loading?

Comment: Have you recently upgraded any of the following: SeleniumLibrary, Selenium or WebDriver?

Comment: A. Koostra you are right! It is possible that those libraries have changed.

Answer (score 0):

A timeout error can have a laundry list of possible issues. Loading a page after a year of smooth operation narrows it down a little, but there are still many possibilities. Connection speeds sometimes change, sometimes the page you're loading up has added features that cause it to take longer to load or was just written poorly so it loads slowly... you get the idea. Without the code of the page or your code to look at, I can only suggest two fixes.

First, in the code of Selenium2Library, there is a timeout variable somewhere that can be set with `Set Selenium Timeout`. The default is 5 seconds, but if your page is taking longer to load, then increasing it might solve your problem. This assumes that your page loads at a reasonable rate in manual testing and that opening it is the least of your concerns.

Second, it's possible that you're testing an AngularJS application, not a normal website. If that's true, then you're going to want to use ExtendedSelenium2Library, not Selenium2Library. ExtendedSelenium2Library is better-equipped to deal with AngularJS applications and includes code to wait for Angular applications to load.

Answer (score 0):

The old webdriver.xpi is buggy about page load handling. Timers are not correctly canceled, resulting in random windows switches and memory leaks. I copy here some replacement code that may be useful to anybody.

```
var WebLoadingListener = function(a, b, c, d) {
  if ("none" == Utils.getPageLoadStrategy()) {
    b(!1, !0);
  } else {
    this.logger = fxdriver.logging.getLogger("fxdriver.WebLoadingListener");
    this.loadingListenerTimer = new fxdriver.Timer;
    this.browser = a;   
    
    var self = this;
    
    var e = function(a, c) {
      self.destroy ();
      b(a, c);
    };
    
    this.handler = buildHandler(a, e, d);
    a.addProgressListener(this.handler);

    -1 == c && (c = 18E5);
    this.loadingListenerTimer.setTimeout(function() {
      e(!0);
    }, c);
    
    WebLoadingListener.listeners [this.handler] = this; 
    goog.log.warning(this.logger, "WebLoadingListener created [" + Object.keys (WebLoadingListener.listeners).length + "] " + d.document.location);
  }
};

WebLoadingListener.listeners = {};

WebLoadingListener.removeListener = function(a, b) {
    if (b.constructor !== WebLoadingListener) {
        b = WebLoadingListener.listeners [b];
    }
    b.destroy ();
};

WebLoadingListener.prototype.destroy = function() {
    if (this.browser) {
        this.loadingListenerTimer.cancel();
        this.browser.removeProgressListener && this.handler && this.browser.removeProgressListener(this.handler);
        delete WebLoadingListener.listeners [this.handler]      
        this.loadingListenerTimer = undefined;
        this.browser = undefined;
        goog.log.warning(this.logger, "WebLoadingListener destroyed [" + Object.keys (WebLoadingListener.listeners).length + "]");
    }
};

enter code here
```